# Pros and cons of CORBA IDL vs RMI?

Tags: rmi, corba, idl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RMI and CORBA Differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898944/rmi-and-corba-differences)

I need to design a client server implementation in java. Client should provide some functionalities and the server should be able to access these remotely with validations,authentications done before accessing them. I am considering CORBA IDL and RMI. They look similar in functionality: both create stubs,skeletons etc. what are the `pros and cons` of each?

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit the question in an attempt to make it more constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicaly, CORBA IDL is very powerful. CORBA allow us to communicate between diferent programming languages and RMI has a bigger comunity, it's easyest to program 'Copy and Paste oriented programming '. :)

PS: For Java i prefer to use JacORB instead of JDK CORBA. 
JacORB has newest versions, implement CORBA 2.3; JacORB IDL compiler is better.

Comment: Iam sorry but i didnot understand "Copy and Paste oriented programming" :( Also can you please give some references for the difference between JacORB and JDK CORBA.

Comment: "Copy and Paste oriented programming", is a joke describing programmers that just copy code from Forums and paste in your own code without understand it.

Comment: I question "RMI has a bigger community". CORBA has been going since the early 1990s. Every JDK and JRE shipped from 1.2 onwards contains an ORB, so in fact the CORBA commnunity is a superset of the Java community let alone the Java RMI community, and as RMI supports IIOP there is another large overlap.

Comment: I don't agree with you. You can see the numbers of tags in stackoverflow to get an ideia about it. RMI has 719 questions and CORBA has 208. The Java community knows RMI better than CORBA